# UMM so IV returns as invalid XLI also comes out invalid and also MDC and MCD returns as invalid, i think there are VERY minor things going on Help pls

Tags: javascript

if (skip) {
skip = false;

```
}else {
  if (nextValue > romanValue) {

    if (romanValue == 5  romanValue == 50  romanValue == 500){ 
      return "Invalid"; 
    }
    arabicNumber = arabicNumber + nextValue - romanValue; 
    skip = true; 


var nextnextValue = dict[romanNumber[i+2]]; 

if (nextnextValue == romanValue)
  return "Invalid";
```

} else {
arabicNumber = arabicNumber + romanValue;

```
}
```

}
UMM so IV returns as invalid
XLI also comes out invalid
and also MDC and MCD returns as invalid, i think there are VERY minor things going on
function RomanToArabic(romanNumber){
var dict = {
"I":1,
"V":5,
"X":10,
"L":50,
"C":100,
"D":500,
"M":1000
};

romanNumber = romanNumber.toUpperCase();

var romanValue = "";

var duplicateCheck = false;

var previousValue = 0;

var consecutiveNumbers = 0;

var skip = false;

var arabicNumber = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < romanNumber.length; i++) {
romanValue = dict[romanNumber[i]];

```
if (romanValue == 5  romanValue == 50  romanValue == 500) {
  duplicateCheck = true; 

  if (duplicateCheck && romanValue == 5  romanValue == 50  romanValue == 500) {
    return "Invalid"; 
  }
}
```

if (previousValue == romanValue) {
consecutiveNumbers = consecutiveNumbers + 1;

```
  if (consecutiveNumbers >= 3 && (romanValue == 1  romanValue == 10   romanValue == 100   romanValue == 1000)) {
    return "Invalid"; 
  }
} 
else {
  consecutiveNumbers = 0; 
} 


var nextValue = dict[romanNumber[i+1]]; 


if (skip) {
  skip = false; 

}else {
  if (nextValue > romanValue) {

    if (romanValue == 5  romanValue == 50 || romanValue == 500){ 
      return "Invalid"; 
    }
    arabicNumber = arabicNumber + nextValue - romanValue; 
    skip = true; 


var nextnextValue = dict[romanNumber[i+2]]; 

if (nextnextValue == romanValue)
  return "Invalid";
```

} else {
arabicNumber = arabicNumber + romanValue;

```
}
```

}

Comment: Please make the title more suitable and add more descriptions.

Comment: Please could you put your code into your question correctly? At the moment some is in as code, some is in as text (so some gets lost). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for  how to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.